# RelativeLayout margin shrinks ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, scaling

I'm trying to dynamically build a layout, so it scales and looks more or less identical on all screen sizes and resolutions. I do this by programmatically placing my views inside a `RelativeLayout` and scaling everything according to a certain factor.

I noticed something strange when moving an `ImageView` around though, the bigger the values on margins get, the smaller the `ImageView` gets. This gets really annoying when trying to get things at right place and size.

```
private void initializeObjects() {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point screenSize = new Point();
    display.getSize(screenSize);

    float scale = screenSize.x / ( (screenSize.x < screenSize.y) ? 480 : 800 ); // Scale according to Galaxy S II resolution
    RelativeLayout screenLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    mRobotView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    mRobotView.setImageResource(R.drawable.soomla_logo_new); // a 743 x 720 png
    mRobotView.setScaleX(scale * 100 / 743); // Make sure the image is 100 "units" in size
    mRobotView.setScaleY(scale * 100 / 720);
    mRobotView.setPivotX(scale * 100 / 743); // reset the image origin according to scale
    mRobotView.setPivotY(scale * 100 / 720);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams robotParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(743, 720);
    robotParams.leftMargin = 0xDEADBEEF; // The bigger these get the smaller the view gets
    robotParams.topMargin  = 0xDEADBEEF;
    screenLayout.addView(mRobotView, robotParams);
}
```

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: If you are using dp/dip units in your layout files, everything would scale automatically. Or is it dynamically because at startup, you don't know what you will need to display?

Comment: Try changing the parent layout's gravity

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:layout_height="720px" 
android:layout_height="743px"
```

in the **main_layout.xml** to have the image not shrinked

Comment: That sets the width/height at a fixed scale, want them to change size according to the screen size.